# Maya Python polySeparate error

Tags: python, command, maya

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.polyChipOff(ltz=0.1, kft=False)
cmds.polySeparate()
```

When running the polySeparate command, I get the error "polySeparate needs exactly 1 polygonal obkect or polygonal faces from one object" despite having a face duplicated and selected.

Total noob here, wondering why this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to pass an object to the polySeparate function.

Since you already have a face selected you can use `cmds.ls` to get the selected object:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.polyChipOff(ltz=0.1, kft=False)
cmds.polySeparate(cmds.ls(sl=True, objectsOnly=True)[0])
```

Works as expected when testing with new objects.